# How to display value of cells for each row?

Tags: jquery, html

in this example, i have a table, i want when i click a button the ID  will be displayed.for example when i click the first button i will have a message contains 1.i use jquery but i don't know which selectors should be used.thanks

table.html

```
 <table border="1">
 <tr>
 <th>ID</th>
 <th>NAME</th>
 <th>ACTION</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>1</td>
 <td>JHON</td>
 <td><input type="button" value="display" class="d"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>2</td>
 <td>Max</td>
 <td><input type="button" value="display" class="d"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>NANCY</td>
<td><input type="button" value="display" class="d"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

file.js

```
$(".d").click(function(){

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is this:

```js
$('input[class="d"]').on('click', function() {
  alert($(this).parent().prev().prev().text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>NAME</th>
    <th>ACTION</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>JHON</td>
    <td><input type="button" value="display" class="d"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Max</td>
    <td><input type="button" value="display" class="d"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>NANCY</td>
    <td><input type="button" value="display" class="d"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you want the answer displayed, but here's some code that will get you started:

```
$(".d").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).parents('td').siblings('td:first-child').text();
    alert('id is = ' + id);
});
```

Working snippet:

```js
$(".d").click(function() {
  var id = $(this).parents('td').siblings('td:first-child').text();
  alert('id is = ' + id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>NAME</th>
    <th>ACTION</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>JHON</td>
    <td><input type="button" value="display" class="d"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Max</td>
    <td><input type="button" value="display" class="d"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>NANCY</td>
    <td><input type="button" value="display" class="d"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".d").click(function() {
  var id = $(this).parent().parent().find(".id");
  alert(id.text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>NAME</th>
    <th>ACTION</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="id">1</td>
    <td>JHON</td>
    <td>
      <input type="button" value="display" class="d">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="id">2</td>
    <td>Max</td>
    <td>
      <input type="button" value="display" class="d">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="id">3</td>
    <td>NANCY</td>
    <td>
      <input type="button" value="display" class="d">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

"this" inside the function gives you access to the clicked element. To make it easier to find the `<td/>` with the ID I added a class .id, this way you can add new columns to the table later without adjusting the JS code.

```
$(".d").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).parent().parent().find(".id");
    alert(id.attr('data-id'));
});
```